# Mostrar detalle de producto en ventana modal Bootstrap-Laravel

Tags: laravel, modal

estoy trabajando sobre una vista en la cual recibo todos los productos desde mi base de datos y tengo un link mediante el cual pretendo mostrar el detalle de dicho producto en una ventana modal. Me funciona pero solo para el primer producto, cuando abro el modal dels egundo producto vuelve a cargarme la info del primer producto...

Tengo definida una ruta donde indico que mi funcion recibira un parametro (id):

```
Route::get('/portfolio/{id}', [PortafolioController::class, 'modalPortfolio'])->name('portfolio.modal.show');
```

En el controlador tengo la funcion propia para mostrar el detalle del producto:

```
   public function modalPortfolio(Portafolio $id){
        //$portfolio = Portafolio::find($id);
        return $id;
    }
```

ademas de la funcion inex (que me retorna el total del productos)

```
   public function index(){
        $portafolio = Portafolio::all();
        return view('portfolio', compact('portafolio'));
       // return view('portfolio');
    }
```

Y finalmente en la vista tengo el codigo para mostrar el total de los productos y el respectivo link para abrir el modal:

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
                @foreach ($portafolio as $item)
                    <div class="box4 col-lg-4">
                            @if($item->imagePortfolio)
                            <img src="{{ asset('storage/'.$item->imagePortfolio->url_img_portfolio)}}" class="card-img-top" >
                            @else
                                <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Others/images/48.jpg" class="card-img-top">
                            @endif
                          <div class="box-content">
                                <a href="   {{ route('portfolio.modal.show', $item->id)}}" class="fa fa-search" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalPortfolio"></a>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                @endforeach
            </div>
```

y finalmente la ventana modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modalPortfolio" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel"><strong>{{$item->titulo_trabajo}}</strong></h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            @if($item->imagePortfolio)
                            <img src="{{ asset('storage/'.$item->imagePortfolio->url_img_portfolio)}}" class="card-img-top" >
                            @else
                                <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Others/images/48.jpg" class="card-img-top">
                            @endif
            <p><strong>Codigo del Proyecto:</strong> DBWEB-{{$item->id}}</p>
            <p><strong>Fecha de Entrega:</strong>  {{$item->fecha_trabajo}}</p>
            <p><strong>Cliente:</strong>  {{$item->cliente}}</p>
            <p><strong>Tecnologia(s) Aplicada(s):</strong>  {{$item->tecnologias_usadas}}</p>
            <p>{{!! $item->descripcion_proyecto !!}}</p>
            <p><strong>Url del Proyecto:</strong>  {{$item->url_proyecto}}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

pero como les comentaba, el modal me abre perfecto pero solo para el primer producto, cuando clico el segundo producto me muestra la info del primero...

Que me estare pasando por alto?

Saludos a todos

Comment: El modal está dentro del foreach?

Comment: estas pasando el mismo id a todos los modales, la pregunta es tienes un solo modal o como estas haciendo?

Comment: Tengo solo un modal compañero

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ no, esta fuera del foreach

Comment: Seguro de que es la info del primer producto, y no del último? Digo porque después del foreach, $item tendría el valor del último objeto de la colección